# winapi listview check item c++

Tags: c++, winapi, listview

I use minGW32 compiler.
I created a ListView with checkbox something like this:

```
HWND hListView = CreateWindowExW(0, WC_LISTVIEWW, L"",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP | LVS_REPORT | LVS_EDITLABELS,
    10,10,500,500, hwnd, (HMENU)ID_LISTVIEW, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
    SendMessage(hListView, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM) font, TRUE);

ListView_SetExtendedListViewStyle(hListView, LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES |  LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | LVS_EX_HEADERDRAGDROP | LVS_EX_GRIDLINES/*LVSCW_AUTOSIZE_USEHEADER*/);

lvc.mask = LVCF_TEXT | LVCF_SUBITEM | LVCF_WIDTH  | LVCF_FMT;
lvc.fmt  = LVCFMT_LEFT;
```

And I would like to check when any checkbox is checked. for example. If I check any checkbox show me a messagebox:

```
I use this WM_NOTIFY:
case WM_NOTIFY:
 {
  switch (LOWORD(wParam))
  {
   case ID_LISTVIEW:
   {
   switch (((LPNMHDR) lParam)->code)
   {
    case LVN_ITEMCHANGED :
    MessageBoxW( NULL, (LPCWSTR)lpMsgBuf, L"Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR ); 
    }
    break; 
   }
  break;
  }
  break;
 }
 break;
```

But this alwas happened. When I click an empty area of the ListView or when just click any item. But I would like to run the messagebox ONLY when the checkbox is changed.

Comment: you can compare the current state of a checkbox with the previous state and only show messagebox if it changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LPNMLISTVIEW pnmv = (LPNMLISTVIEW) lParam; 

if(pnmv->uChanged & LVIF_STATE) // item state has been changed
{
   switch(pnmv->uNewState & LVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK)
   {
   case INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2):
      // pnmv->iItem was checked
      break;
   case INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(1):
      //pnmv->iItem was unchecked
      break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I've got one question I am very new in winapi programming what means 0x3000, and where can I find the other options?

Comment: @CarlMark: `0x3000 == 0x2000 | 0x1000` ... it masks out the bits checked *inside* the `switch/case`. Otherwise you'd check against more than those two lowest significant bits.

Comment: @LefterisE could you help in this question?

Comment: I edited my answer to remove the hard-coded values. I couldn't find a proper documentation but I mapped the constant 0x2000 to the macro INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(2). The value 0x2000 i got from googling and the modification is based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774733(v=vs.85).aspx